# Unrecoverable IL error, but the IL looks fine

Tags: .net, compiler-errors, cil, intermediate-language

I'm getting errors with the following IL.  Any idea why?  It looks fine to me!

[image]

The issue is with the lines `stloc.4/ldloc.4` that are highlighted in bold.

The syntax highlighting is from Rider, but I get the same issue with `ilasm` as well.

I'm running this on MacOS.

Comment: The error message from ilasm is:

`/. . . /build/tmpHpGfMu.il(180) : error : syntax error at token 'stloc' in: stloc.4`

which is not really that helpful, considering that the other variable initialisations seemed to be fine...

Comment: Don't put [image of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: no problem.  I'll correct that shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that there's no `stloc.4`, `stloc.x` goes up to 3. You should use [`stloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc) followed by number, e.g. `stloc 4`. Since index of variable is less than 255, it's possible to use `stloc.s 4` to save few bytes in resulting assembly. Same applies to `ldloc.4` at next line